# Parsing input and output currency names

Tags: python, parsing

The input for price() would be STRINGS, as you see below. If the string starts with "-" I would like what follows to be stored in fiat_name and then retrieve the symbol from _KNOWN_FIAT_SYMBOLS. "--rub" (EXAMPLE) could be at any position in the list passed through price()

If the optional fiat_name does not exist in _KNOWN_FIAT_SYMBOLS i would like it to default to USD/$

I would like the code optimized and cleaned/minimized. I am trying to practice clean and read-able code.

```
import re

_KNOWN_FIAT_SYMBOLS = {"USD":"$", "RUB":"₽"} # this will be populated with more symbols/pairs later


def price(*arguments):
    # default to USD/$
    fiat_name = "USD"

    arguments = list(arguments)
    cryptos = []

    for arg in arguments:
        arg = arg.strip()
            
        if not arg:
            continue

        for part in arg.split(","):
            if part.startswith("-"):

                fiat_name = part.upper().lstrip("-")
                    
                continue
                
            crypto = re.sub("[^a-z0-9]", "", part.lower())
                
            if crypto not in cryptos:
                cryptos.append(crypto)

    if not cryptos:
        cryptos.append("btc")
            
    fiat_symbol = _KNOWN_FIAT_SYMBOLS.get(fiat_name)
        
    if not fiat_symbol:
        fiat_name = "USD"
        fiat_symbol = "$"

    print(f"{cryptos} to: {fiat_name}{fiat_symbol}")


price("usd", "usdc", "--rub") # ['usd', 'usdc'] to: RUB₽ (becuase of the optional --rub)
price("usd,usdc,eth", "btc", "-usd") # ['usd', 'usdc', 'eth', 'btc'] to: USD$ (becuase of the optional --usd)
price("usd", "usdc,btc", "-xxx") #['usd', 'usdc', 'btc'] to: USD$ (because xxx does not exist in _KNOWN_FIAT_SYMBOLS
price("usd,usdc,eth", "btc") # ['usd', 'usdc', 'eth', 'btc'] to: USD$ (becuase no optional fiat_name was given)
price("usd,--rub,eth", "btc") # ['usd', 'eth', 'btc'] to: RUB₽ (becuase of the optional --rub)
price("--rub") # ['btc'] to: RUB₽ (becuase of the optional --rub and the cryptos is empty)
price("") # ['btc'] to: USD$ (becuase of the default USD and the cryptos is empty)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Return data**. Algorithmic code should return data, not print – at least
whenever feasible. It's better for testing, debugging, refactoring, and
probably other reasons. At a minimum, return a plain tuple or dict. Even better
would be a meaningful data object of some kind (e.g., `namedtuple`,
`dataclass`, or `attrs` class). Print elsewhere, typically in
a function operating at the outer edge of your program.

**Function `*args` are already independent tuples**. That means you don't need
`arguments = list(arguments)`.

**Algorithmic readability**. Your current code is generally fine: I had no
great difficulty figuring out how it was supposed to work. However, the parsing
rules themselves have a tendency to require an annoying amount of conditional
logic: I was not happy with the first draft or two I sketched out. But I did
come up with an alternative that I ended up liking better: one function
focuses on parsing just the currency names (a fairly narrow, textual task); and
the other part deals with the annoyances of missing/unknown data. Note that
both functions return meaningful data objects – an important tool in writing
more readable code – and the second function handles missing/unknown values
with a "declarative" style. Overall, this version strikes me as somewhat more
readable. If you need to optimize for raw speed, it's probably slower.

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

_KNOWN_FIAT_SYMBOLS = {"USD":"$", "RUB":"₽"}

FiatCryptos = namedtuple('FiatCryptos', 'name symbol cryptos')
Currency = namedtuple('Currency', 'name is_fiat')

def price(*arguments):
    currencies = list(parse_currencies(arguments))
    cryptos = [c.name for c in currencies if not c.is_fiat] or ['btc']
    fiats = [c.name.upper() for c in currencies if c.is_fiat] or ['USD']
    f = fiats[0]
    syms = _KNOWN_FIAT_SYMBOLS
    name, sym = (f, syms[f]) if f in syms else ('USD', '$')
    return FiatCryptos(name, sym, cryptos)

def parse_currencies(arguments):
    for arg in arguments:
        for part in arg.strip().split(','):
            if part:
                is_fiat = part.startswith('-')
                name = re.sub('[^a-z0-9]', '', part.lower())
                yield Currency(name, is_fiat)
```